# Automator: Combine PDF pages double or triple in size

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, pdf

I have the following workflow: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhuddCrCrmwRfJPe9M0QoamWwNm9U_Nm/view?usp=sharing

Here's the desired outcome: I select a file, it splits it and I rebuild it as smaller sections of the PDF. Basically, an even better version of this workflow (or applescript) would split a PDF in half. I have been unsuccessful.

When I run my workflow, it creates a folder with all the different pages of the PDF. When I reselect half of those and combine them, it doubles or triples in size. That seems backwards, but it looks like the workflow is creating a repeating looped document. Super confused.

Image of workflow: [image]

Comment: wdym *"rebuild it as a smaller PDF."*?

Comment: Because certain OCR sites namely space.ocr has a size limit. I'll edit it to clarify that I'm building two smaller sections.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using [PDF Sam](https://pdfsam.org/). Description from website:

> Merge, split, extract pages, rotate and mix your PDF files. Runs on
>   Windows, Mac, Linux and any other operating system where a Java
>   Runtime Environment (with JavaFX) version 8 or above is available.
>   Free and open source since 2006.

Just download the program, which is a PDF tool, and then stick your PDF in it. Once you've done that, you can chose the option to split the PDF.